# Adding Marshmallow permissions using "Permissions Dispatcher"

Tags: java, android, plugins, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm successfully using Permission Dispatcher to handle Marshmallow permissions.
Is there a way to use it on a static class, where I cannot access to "this" in ${className}PermissionDispatcher.${method}WitchCheck(this) ?

Working example:

```java
@RuntimePermissions
public class ContactsMapFragment extends mFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (DeviceUtils.isMarshmallow())
            ContactsMapFragmentPermissionsDispatcher.setMapLocationWithCheck(this, googleMap);
        else
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    protected void setMapLocation(@NonNull GoogleMap gmap) {
        gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

But in this other snippet I have a static class, so **this** doesn't exist:

```java
@RuntimePermissions
public class PhoneUtils
{
    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
    public static void makeCall(String szNumber)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_CALL, // place a phone call directly
                Uri.parse("tel:" + szNumber)
        );

        mActivity activity = Muffin.getInstance().getActivity();
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        if (DeviceUtils.isMarshmallow())
            PhoneHelperPermissionDispatcher.startCallWithCheck(this, activity, intent);
        else
            activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void startCall(mActivity activity, Intent intent)
    {
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a little bit of your relevant code?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static class can't be annotated because only Activity and Fragment are allowed, as Android Framework just provides requestPermission method on Activity and Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Permission Dispatcher library but I think you can pass the Activity or Context to methods of static class and can use it.

or

You can use Application class to keep context global.

for example:

```
public class MyDemoApplication extends Application {

private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyDemoApplication .context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MyDemoApplication.context;
}
```

}

You have to call `MyDemoApplication.getAppContext()` to get your application context statically from any class file.

Note: If you are extending Application class in your project then don't forget to specify its name in application tag of manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

See below links for more details:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/